# Correct using of standard IMU sensor messages in ROS Callbacks?

Tags: python, ros2

I would like to use standard IMU sensor messages  defined in ROS as [standard sensor IMU message](http://docs.ros.org/en/melodic/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/Imu.html)instead of custom one in my python ROS2 nodes. I defined correctly the IMU sensor message in the message file. Also in the python3 code I have imported correctly with `from sensor_msgs.msg import Imu`.. So, somewhere in my python code I would like to use this sensor message for example in this Callback here:

```
def imu_cb(self, msg: Imu):
            """
            Update the joint states message to be published using info from imu msg.
    
            @param msg imu message
            @return processing return code (True: could be processed; False: could not)
            """
            q = msg.imu.orientation
            try:
                r = R.from_quat([q.x, q.y, q.z, q.w]).as_rotvec()
            except ValueError as e:
                self.logger.warn(f'{e}')
                return False
    
            self._joint_states.position[0] = -r[2] if self._inv_imu else r[2]
            return True
```

So in the Callback function in the line `q = msg.imu.orientation` Im not sure is correct . I think it should be `q = msg.orientation`. Any help which one is correct?

Comment: What happens when you use your suggested solutions?  We are not a debugging service

Comment: no. Im just asking the correct implementation of standard IMU messages